Converting a very large (250GB+) json file into csv using ijson in Python
I'm trying to convert an extremely large (over 250GB) json file into a csv; the json file looks like this:
{
"BuildingSiteList":[
    {
    "ID": "00001"
    (34 more attributes)
    },
    {
    "ID": "00002"
    (34 more attributes)
    }
},
{
"BuildingSiteOwnershipList":[
    {
    "Owner": "xyz"
    (14 more attributes)
    },
    {
    "Owner": "abc"
    (14 more attributes)
    }
},
{
"BuildingsList":[
    {
    "ID":"000003"
    "LocalityCode":"01"
    (89 more attributes)
    },
    {
    "ID":"000004"
    "LocalityCode":"03"
    (89 more attributes)
    },
    {
    etc.
    }
},
and so on

I am only interested in part of the data that falls under the "BuildingsList" branch, so I am currently using this python code to find the desired attributes and put them into a csv file:
import ijson
import csv

input_file_path = 'path to json file' output_file_path = 'path to csv file'
 # List the fieldnames you want to include in the CSV file
desired_fieldnames = [ "ID" "localityCode" "Coordinates" "BuildingType" "RentalStatus" ]

 # Buffer to store rows before writing to CSV
buffer_size = 1000000 chunky = 100000 rows_buffer = []
def write_buffer(writer, buffer): for row in buffer: writer.writerow(row)
with open(input_file_path, 'rb') as input_file, open(output_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as output_file: objects = ijson.items(input_file, "BuildingsList") writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=desired_fieldnames) writer.writeheader()

for item in objects:
    # Create a new dictionary with only the desired fields
    for x in range (len(item)):
        filtered_item = {field: item[x].get(field, '') for field in desired_fieldnames}
        rows_buffer.append(filtered_item)

    if len(rows_buffer) >= buffer_size:
        write_buffer(writer, rows_buffer)
        rows_buffer = []

# Write any remaining rows in the buffer
if rows_buffer:
    write_buffer(writer, rows_buffer)

This works fine on a smaller version of the dataset (60kb) but it crashes my computer when I try to use it on the large file. I assume this is because ijson.items tries to process the entire dataset.
I tried to use pandas to split the json file into manageable chunks but couldn't get it to work.

Can you fix your demo json and your code please so we can see what is going on.

Please format your code

BuildingsList.item is the ijson prefix you want to use

I don't know ijson at all but if it stream reads json so that you don't have to read in the entire payload then I might expect this to work.
import ijson
import csv

input_file_path = 'path to json file'
output_file_path = 'path to csv file'
desired_fieldnames = [ "ID" "localityCode" "Coordinates" "BuildingType" "RentalStatus" ]

with open(input_file_path, 'rb') as input_file, open(output_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=desired_fieldnames, extrasaction="ignore")
    writer.writeheader()
    for item in ijson.items(input_file, "BuildingsList.item"):
        writer.writerow(item)

